# Deleted answer on Selenium Webdriver question

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers, moderators

I recently answered this question:

[selenium 2 chrome driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7450416/selenium-2-chrome-driver)

My answer was:

*There is an open source utility called "webdrivermanager" to handle WebDriver binaries (chromedriver, operadriver, IEDriverServer) in Java. This library downloads the latest version of the WebDriver binary you need, store it in the Maven local repository (.m2/repository), and export the proper Java system variable (webdriver.chrome.driver, webdriver.opera.driver, webdriver.ie.driver):*

*https://github.com/bonigarcia/webdrivermanager*

*Simply adding this dependency to your Maven project:*

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
   <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
   <version>1.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

*... you can invoke the following methods and webdrivermanager does to the trick for you:*

```
ChromeDriverManager.setup();
InternetExplorerDriverManager.setup();
OperaDriverManager.setup();
```

*Then you can create your WebDriver object (ChromeDriver, OperaDriver, InternetExplorerDriver) to carry out automated web browsing.*

My answer was deleted by [bluefeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/426671/bluefeet) moderator.

Why did you delete my answer?

IMHO my answer is a valuable contribution to the topic. The library I speak there is an open-source library I made myself and I released to the community. Even if the selected answer if other, I think my contribution could help a lot of people.

Comment: *"However, you must disclose your affiliation in your answers."* http://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion

Answer (score 8):

There were a few reasons why I deleted [your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29231181/426671).  Since it's been deleted it is available to 10K+ users only so here's a screenshot.

> [image]

We received a flag on it because you posted the exact [same answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29230422/426671) to another question. Basically copy and pasting the same answer to multiple questions isn't the proper way to be answering questions. An answer should be specific to the question being asked. If you can copy and paste an answer, then you should answer one of the questions and then flag or vote to close the other question as a duplicate.

Now, as others have pointed out this is your library but you failed [to disclose your affiliation with the product](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion) as explained in the Help Center. It specifically states:

> The community here tends to vote down overt self-promotion and flag it as spam. Post good, relevant answers, and if some (but not all) happen to be about your product or website, that’s okay. However, you must disclose your affiliation in your answers.

Next time you want to post answers to your library please keep this in mind. Disclose your affiliate and close as dups instead of posting the same answer in multiple places.